# semantic release random branch as a release branch

Tags: semantic-release

how should [semantic release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) be configured to produce a unique semantic versioning for each branch (set all branches as release branch).

that is, assume a random branch name - how do semantic release should be configured to make the random branch as a release branch, such that semantic release will produce a unique semantic versioning for that branch. e.g. `1.2.3-<branch name>+<ref>`?